# Stream9,tunctl,yum -y install tunctl

Tags: linux

I would like to ask if the tunctl command can be installed on starem9? I have been reading information related to namespace recently and want to learn more.

I searched for information, but couldn't find it. I used yum -y install tunctl, but it didn't work.